# Memcache socket/port

Tags: sockets, web, memcached, port

I implemented memcache server listening on a TCP port. Later I found that UNIX domain sockets are faster than TCP sockets. While using TCP, my number of active connections were getting drastically high. Then I started using memcache with UNIX domain sockets and performance got improved.

Now I have to use multiple web servers and I am puzzled how to use memcache with UNIX domain sockets. One thing which I have to keep in mind that My web server has to use single memcache server.

Please suggest how can I incorporate memcache using UNIX domain sockets. Or if I use TCP then how can I improve performance. Any other optimization solutions are most welcome.

Comment: What do you mean by "with port" and "with socket"? memcache always listens on a (TCP or UDP) port, and clients use a socket to connect to that port. Perhaps if you show some code your meaning will become clear.

Comment: Memcache->connect(<host>,<port>);

 Memcache->connect('unix:///tmp/memcached.sock',0);

Later one is faster.

Comment: OK, so it sounds like you are actually talking about using UNIX domain sockets vs. TCP sockets. You shouldn't call that "sockets" and "ports", it makes no sense. I will edit your question according to what I think you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "My web server has to use single memcache server" you mean that your web server(s) must connect to a remote central memcache server then of course TCP is your only option since [UNIX domain sockets are only local](https://serverfault.com/questions/339446/are-there-any-drawbacks-to-running-memcached-on-a-unix-domain-socket-instead-of).

If your web server(s) are only making connections to a memcache server running on the local machine then UNIX domain sockets will work fine and you should use them if they are faster.